# How can I sample from one tensorflow Dataset according to a given probability distribution?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have seen that with [tf.contrib.data.sample_from_datasets()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/sample_from_datasets) now one can sample from different datasets according to a given probability distribution. However, I'm interested in sampling random chunks of data *within a single* Dataset.

At the moment I'm using a `tf.data` iterator and I'm initializing it from a generator that makes use of [np.random.choice()](http://sample_from_datasets) to produce the first indices of the chunks to sample, as `np.random.choice()` accepts a custom probability distribution as input. This method is clunky and I think not as fast as it could be if I could use tensorflow's Datasets for all the steps.

Is there a known way of achieving this?